# Trouble selecting text in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I'm encountering some strange issues when selecting text by either using shift or double clicking a word in Visual Studio 2015. The selection immediately gets deselected.

A picture is worth a thousand words. Have a look:

[image]

I'm using Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 Update 1.
Is anyone else also encountering this issue and found a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue appeared to be caused by my Wacom Bamboo tablet. Selecting text with a regular mouse worked without any problem.

The recently released update 2 for VS2015 did fix this problem.